# OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded android

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, execute

In android studio 1.5.1 just by moving the source code from one system to another and Even though the clean build is successful but while the code is run I am getting this kind of error

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded Error:Execution
>   failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. >
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero
>   exit value 3

I added the below code in app.gradle also:

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Comment: Is your JVM 64 bit?  If yes, you can't get more than 1.7 GB of heap.

Answer (score 3):

Updated gradle plugin use R8 process by default to code shrinking. You can try this by adding following lines in **gradle.proeprties**.

> org.gradle.daemon=true

> org.gradle.configureondemand=true

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: This helped me get past R8 not completing its process after upgrading to use Android 8. (heap errors; out of memory) The old proguard/dexoptions usage was needed for the prior versions. R8 didn't care how much mem I allocated via the previous dexOptions values.

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g" // WAY overkill, but beats an occasional out of memory error when building
    }

Answer (score 2):

`GC overhead limit exceeded` means that your app occupied all the heap and garbage collector cannot clean enough space to run the program.

So, there is too much necessary data in memory or memory leak (i.e. references which can be accessed from app root but no longer needed) exists in your application - only further app profiling can give you more details

Answer (score 2):

The detail message `"GC overhead limit exceeded"` indicates that the garbage collector is running all the time and Java program is making very slow progress. After a garbage collection, if the Java process is spending more than approximately 98% of its time doing garbage collection and if it is recovering less than 2% of the heap and has been doing so far the last 5 (compile time constant) consecutive garbage collections, then a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown. This exception is typically thrown because the amount of live data barely fits into the Java heap having little free space for new allocations.
Action: Increase the heap size. The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception for GC Overhead limit exceeded can be turned off with the command line flag -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit.

This was taken from Oracle Java Documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your allocated memory for the app by adding

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to your manifest file and see if it solves your problem.
But you should look for memory leaks in your app because the OutOfMemoryError is usually a consequence of bad memory management.

Comment: I think the OP was talking about memory allocation for Android Studio running a compile, not the app being built.