# Android Robolectric: OutOfMemoryError - GC overhead limit exceeded, when Creating ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, garbage-collection, robolectric

I want to create a test for a method that returns an `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` type is a custom object called `DateItem`. But when I try to create the `ArrayList` in my test code (which is placed in `test` folder), the test failed with the following message:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Here's my code:

```
var expectedDateItems: ArrayList<DateItem> = ArrayList()
val currentDate = date1Start
while (currentDate.isBefore(date1End)) {
    val dateItem = DateItem(currentDate, ArrayList())
    expectedDateItems.add(dateItem)
    currentDate.plusDays(1)
}
```

I am wondering how to create such ArrayList in my test code. I've looked into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36131976/8434188) but it is for the whole app, not only for testing purposes. How to allocate more memory for unit testing?

EDIT: After debugging, the code failed when in this line: `val dateItem = DateItem(currentDate, ArrayList())`.

Comment: Your while condition ends up doing way too much iterations. I suspect `currentDate.plusDays(1)` does not change `currentDate`. Maybe it should be re-assigned to `currentDate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you have endless WHILE loop because `currentDate.plusDays(1)` return [copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-) of `currentDate`. Change to:

```
currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1)
```

Comment: I just realized this, spot on!